# angularjs move focus to next control on enter

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way, when hitting enter inside a form, the focus to go to the next input instead submitting the form with angularjs.

I have a form with a lot of fields and customers are used to hit enter to move to the next input (comming from desktop applications). The angularjs saves the form when the user hits enter. I like to change this. Is it possible ?

Comment: I suggest writing a directive for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest making a custom directive. Something like this. I haven't tested this.

```js
.directive('focus', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope,elem,attrs) {

      elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code === 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          elem.next().focus();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Something like that should work. You might have to tweek something. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I will try. I need to find a way how to prevent form submit when hitting enter (yet do not know if your code prevents this)

Comment: I edited it and it works perfectly. I tested it out. Bam. Just stick the word "focus" in any input elements you want to work that way.

Comment: One change, use this for a more usable version. elem.nextAll('input').first().focus();

Comment: When this answer was written those were built in Angular.Element methods. Easy enough to change to addEvenyListener and nextSibling

Answer (score 11):

Create a custom directive:

```
.directive('nextOnEnter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, selem, attrs) {
            selem.bind('keydown', function (e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code === 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var pageElems = document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea'),
                        elem = e.srcElement || e.target,
                        focusNext = false,
                        len = pageElems.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var pe = pageElems[i];
                        if (focusNext) {
                            if (pe.style.display !== 'none') {
                                angular.element(pe).focus();
                                break;
                            }
                        } else if (pe === elem) {
                            focusNext = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Had to make a couple tweaks. One: `e.srcElement` is specific to old IE so  `e.srcElement || e.target` works instead. `pe === e.srcElement` needs to be `pe === elem` and `pe.focus()` becomes `angular.element(pe).focus()`

Comment: Awesome. This works. My only problem is that it does not work with select / md-select. Can we do something about it?

Comment: Not bad.. but it doesn't work with tabindex property. But it work better than other answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the directive I ended up with (thanks to Zack Argyle):

```
    

    angular.module('myApp').directive("nextFocus", nextFocus);

    /** Usage:
      <input next-focus id="field1">
      <input next-focus id="field2">
      <input id="field3">
      Upon pressing ENTER key the directive will switch focus to
      the next field id e.g field2
      The last field should not have next-focus directive to avoid
      focusing on non-existing element.
      Works for Web, iOS (Go button) & Android (Next button) browsers, 
    **/

    function nextFocus() {
      var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
            var partsId = attrs.id.match(/field(\d{1})/);
            var currentId = parseInt(partsId[1]);

            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (code === 13) {
              e.preventDefault();
              document.querySelector('#field' + (currentId + 1)).focus();
            }
          });
        }
      };
      return directive;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried this solution out. As advertised, it needed some tweaking. Here is what ended up working for me:

```
.directive("focus", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
                var focusables = $(":focusable");
                elem.bind("keydown", function (e) {
                    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    if (code === 13) {
                        var current = focusables.index(this);
                        var next = focusables.eq(current + 1).length ? focusables.eq(current + 1) : focusables.eq(0);
                        next.focus();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Note that the in order to get the `:focusable` pseudo to work, you will need to reference JQueryUI. (the latest version 1.11.4 worked for me)

Answer (score 2):

This is the directive I ended up with (thanks to Zack Argyle and Oleg):

```
app.directive("nextFocus", function () {

    /** Usage:
      <input next-focus tabindex="0" id="field1">
      <input next-focus tabindex="1" id="field2">
      <input id="field3">
      Upon pressing ENTER key the directive will switch focus to
      the next field id e.g field2
      The last field should not have next-focus directive to avoid
      focusing on non-existing element.
      Works for Web, iOS (Go button) & Android (Next button) browsers, 
    **/
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('keydown', function (e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code === 13) {
                    try {
                        if (attrs.tabindex != undefined) {
                            var currentTabIndex = attrs.tabindex;
                            var nextTabIndex = parseInt(attrs.tabindex) + 1;
                            $("[tabindex=" + nextTabIndex + "]").focus();
                        }
                    } catch (e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return directive;

});
```

Comment: What if I don't want to use jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by wolcy97 but using only angular

```
 /** Usage:
  <input next-focus tabindex="0">
  <input next-focus tabindex="1">
  <input tabindex="2">
  Upon pressing ENTER key the directive will switch focus to
  the next tabindex.
  The last field should not have next-focus directive to avoid
  focusing on non-existing element.
  Works for Web, iOS (Go button) & Android (Next button) browsers, 
**/ 
 app.directive('nextFocus', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code === 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          try {
            if (attrs.tabindex !== undefined) {
              var currentTabeIndex = attrs.tabindex;
              var nextTabIndex = parseInt(currentTabeIndex) + 1;
              var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[tabindex]");
              for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
                var el = angular.element(elems[i]);
                var idx = parseInt(el.attr('tabindex'));
                if (idx === nextTabIndex) {
                  elems[i].focus();
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('Focus error: ' + e);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Works very well with tabindex. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript Enter as TAB

```
angular.module('app').directive('tabNext', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem) {

        elem.bind('keyup', function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (code === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var eIDX = -1;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.form.elements.length; i++) {
                    if (elem.eq(this.form.elements[i])) {
                         eIDX = i;
                         break;
                    }
                }
                if (eIDX === -1) {
                    return;
                }
                var j = eIDX + 1;
                var theform = this.form;
                while (j !== eIDX) {
                    if (j >= theform.elements.length){
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    if ((theform.elements[j].type !== "hidden") && (theform.elements[j].type !== "file")
                            && (theform.elements[j].name !== theform.elements[eIDX].name) 
                            && (! theform.elements[j].disabled) 
                            && (theform.elements[j].tabIndex >= 0)) {
                        if (theform.elements[j].type === "select-one") {
                            theform.elements[j].focus();
                        } else if (theform.elements[j].type === "button") {
                            theform.elements[j].focus();
                        } else {
                            theform.elements[j].focus();
                            theform.elements[j].select();
                        }
                        return;
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>S No</th>
                                            <th>Stock Id</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Qty</th>
                                            <th>UOM</th>
                                            <th>Rate</th>
                                            <th>Amount</th>

                                            <th>Add</th>
                                            <th>Delete</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="item in stockitems">
                                            <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                            <td>

                                                <input type="text" style="width:70px" id="stkid{{$index}}" class="form-control" name="stockid" required insert="Addnewrow();" ng-keyup="moveFocus('desc','amount','stkid','stkid',$index,$event)" ng-blur="getStockitem($index);" typeahead="a.stockitem_code as (a.stockitem_code +' | ' + a.stockitem_name +' | '+ a.rate) for a in stock | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" data-ng-model="item.stockid" rows="3" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc{{$index}}" name="description" ng-keyup="moveFocus('quantity','stkid','desc','desc',$index,$event)" data-ng-model="item.description" rows="3" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                                <input type="text" style="width:70px" id="quantity{{$index}}" class="form-control" ng-keyup="moveFocus('uom','desc','quantity','quantity',$index,$event)" ng-change="GetAmount($index,'qty');" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" required name="qty" data-ng-model="item.qty" rows="3" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                                <input type="text" style="width:70px" id="uom{{$index}}" class="form-control" name="uom" ng-keyup="moveFocus('rate','quantity','uom','uom',$index,$event)" data-ng-model="item.uom" required rows="3" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>


                                                <input type="text" style="width:70px" id="rate{{$index}}" class="form-control" name="rate" ng-keyup="moveFocus('amount','uom','rate','rate',$index,$event)" required data-ng-model="item.rate" ng-pattern="/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,9})?$/" ng-change="GetAmount($index,'rate');" rows="3" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>

                                                <input type="text" style="width:70px" id="amount{{$index}}" class="form-control" ng-keyup="moveFocus('stkid','rate','amount','amount',$index,$event)" name="amount" required data-ng-model="item.amount" rows="3" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td><span ng-click="AddEstimation($index);"><a>Add</a></span></td>
                                            <td><span ng-click="DeleterowEstimation($index);"><a>Delete</a></span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.moveFocus = function (nextId,prevId,downId,upId,index,event) {
            debugger;
            if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                nextId = nextId + index;
                $('#' + nextId).focus();
            }
            else if(event.keyCode == 37)
            {
                prevId = prevId + index;
                $('#' + prevId).focus();
            }
            else if(event.keyCode == 38)
            {
                upId = upId + (index - 1);
                $('#' + upId).focus();
            }
            else if(event.keyCode == 40)
            {
                downId = downId + (index + 1);
                $('#' + downId).focus();
            }
            else if(event.keyCode==13)
            {
                if (nextId == "desc") {
                    nextId = "quantity" + index;
                    $('#' + nextId).focus();
                }
                else if(nextId == "uom")
                {
                    nextId = "stkid" + (index + 1);
                    $('#' + nextId).focus();
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Refer below html

Answer (score -1):

**On Enter press it moves to next element of DOM, but element requires id to set focus**

```
starter.directive('focustonext', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, selem, attrs) {
        selem.bind('keydown', function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (code === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var pageElems = document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea'),
                    elem = e.srcElement || e.target,
                    focusNext = false,
                    len = pageElems.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    var pe = pageElems[i];
                    if (focusNext) {
                        if (pe.style.display !== 'none') {                               
                            document.getElementById(pe.id).focus();
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (pe === elem) {
                        focusNext = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
   }
});
```

*Thanks all..*