# change focus to the next input text with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have an object variable in my controller (var myObject), divided into 3 input text in the IHM.

I want to change automatically the focus to the next input when the focused one reached the maxLength.

```
var myObject = {
   part1:"",
   part2:"",
   part3:""
}



<form>
    <input type="text" id="part1" ng-model="myObject.part1" maxlength="7"/>
    <input type="text" id="part2" ng-model="myObject.part2" maxlength="12"/>
    <input type="text" id="part2" ng-model="myObject.part2" maxlength="12"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe, the following may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086865/angularjs-move-focus-to-next-control-on-enter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd need to use a directive for this:

```
app.directive("moveNextOnMaxlength", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope, element) {
            element.on("input", function(e) {
                if(element.val().length == element.attr("maxlength")) {
                    var $nextElement = element.next();
                    if($nextElement.length) {
                        $nextElement[0].focus();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And update your form as follows:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="part1" ng-model="myObject.part1" maxlength="7" move-next-on-maxlength />
    <input type="text" id="part2" ng-model="myObject.part2" maxlength="12" move-next-on-maxlength />
    <input type="text" id="part2" ng-model="myObject.part2" maxlength="12"/>
</form>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z02L5gbx/)

You *could* move the directive onto the `<form>` element instead, but the build-int jqLite's `find()` method will restrict you to only finding elements by tag name. If you're using full jQuery, or can use vanillaJS instead, I would suggest this method.

Comment: Thank you for that but you can't compare an 'int' with a 'String':
should be:
if(element.val().length == element[0].maxLength)...

Comment: @grindking Of course you can, this is Javascript! :) `12 == "12"`. As long as you don't use *strict* equality, you'll generally be fine.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Didn't work for me because of that reason: 'use strict';
Thank you anyway. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer works, but only if the fields are immediate siblings. If for example you have 3 fields each in there own column, you need a different solution:

```
angular
.module('move-next-directive', [])
.directive('moveNextOnMaxlength',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on('input', function(e) {
          var partsId = attrs.id.match(/focus(\d+)/);
          var currentId = parseInt(partsId[1]);

          var l = elem.val().length;
          if (l == elem.attr("maxlength")) {
            nextElement = document.querySelector('#focus' + (currentId + 1));
            nextElement.focus();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Add a numbered "focus" id to each input field:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" id="focus1" maxlength="4" move-next-on-maxlength />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" id="focus2" maxlength="4" move-next-on-maxlength />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" id="focus3" maxlength="4" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Credits to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33007493/3319392

Comment: I used this version as my inputs were in different spans, thanks. I did have to change your regex to allow for more than 10 elements, this allows an infinite number named focus*:  `var partsId = attrs.id.match(/focus(\d+)/);`

Comment: Thanks @eric ... I have edited the code as suggested to allow an infinite number of focus fields.