# Close android keyboard on the last field of a form

Tags: javascript, forms, keyboard, tablet

Is there a way to close the android keyboard when I'm on the last input of a form, already filled it, and click on the keyboard 'enter' button? It's a web app built with angularjs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the 'enter' button you could [focus](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) on an element (an `<a>` for example) and this should hide the soft keyboard. 
Details to catch the enter button here: [angularjs move focus to next control on enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086865/angularjs-move-focus-to-next-control-on-enter)